# Missing entire desktop that contained my files, folders, short cuts, and start menu from windows-10

Tags: windows-10

My question is how to retrieve my (Windows-10) original desktop that disappeared with all my folders, files, shortcuts, and start menu?
In searching for answers I saw names of my files, from my original desktop, listed in Indexed Locations. May I please have suggestions on how to retrieve from index and make them viable?

Comment: Consider adding details, such as how your desktop disappeared (IE: Did you get a new internal disk, did this happen after Windows update, etc...).

Comment: happened around the time  I removed an old user name that was reportedly found on the dark web

Comment: If you created a new user account why would you expect to have the desktop?

Comment: Good point Gabriela. I should have framed that differently.

Comment: cont... @Gabriela [@Ulincsys] At that time, Microsoft would not let me change my original sign-in email, only allowing alias(s). So I went about using all the new things I'd set-up instead. Time passed, I didn't give the dark-web a thought until...some time back, Up-pops my old email on some site. I freaked again and deleted it.  There also were, 2 or so, updates since then.   I shouldn't have even tried to add details at 2 in the morning. Sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: See if the old user folder is still in C:/users/